# Clunky calculation of differences between an incrementing set of numbers, is there a more beautiful way?

Tags: python, list

The following code works just fine. But it seems so verbose, surely there is a more elegant way to calculate this?

The idea is that I have a list of 100 incrementing timestamps, I want to look at those timestamps and calculate the mean time between each time-stamp.

The code below functions, but I'm sure it's really inefficient to be reversing lists like this.

Any suggestions?

```
#!/usr/bin/python 

nums = [1,4,6,10]
print nums
nums_orig = list(nums)

nums_orig.pop()
nums.reverse()
nums.pop()
nums.reverse()

print nums
print nums_orig

total = 0

for idx, val in enumerate(nums):
  difference = val - nums_orig[idx]
  total += difference
  print idx, val - nums_orig[idx]

print "Mean difference is %d" % (total / len(nums))
```

Comment: Observation: the answer in your example is `3`, which is suspiciously identical to `(last - first) / (count - 1)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is

```
>>> nums = [1,4,6,10]
>>> [x-y for x,y in zip(nums[1:],nums)]
[3, 2, 4]
>>> delta=[x-y for x,y in zip(nums[1:],nums)]
>>> float(sum(delta))/len(delta)
3.0
```

Solution with using Starmap

```
>>> from itertools import starmap
>>> from operator import sub
>>> sum(starmap(sub,zip(nums[1:],nums)))/float(len(nums)-1)
3.0
```

Comment: Minor naming criticism: you've called your list of delta values `mean`, seems needlessly  confusing.

Comment: You are using truncating integer division instead of floating point division. `mean` is not an apt variable name for a list; try something like `deltas`

Comment: @JohnMachin: Makes sense. Implemented the suggestion.

Answer (score 8):

If you have numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.diff([1,4,6,10]).mean()
3.0
```

Comment: Sorry dude, super elegant but the second answer gave me more insight.

Answer (score 3):

> The idea is that I have a list of 100 incrementing timestamps, I want to look at those timestamps and calculate the mean time between each time-stamp.

Since they are increasing, the sum of the differences is simply the difference between the first and last. The number of differences, meanwhile, is simply 1 less than the number of values.

So no looping is needed. Just:

```
(nums[-1] - nums[0])/(len(nums) - 1)
```

Comment: +1 Well spotted. But it actually doesn't matter that they are increasing, they can do anything, and you are still correct - its effectively a conservative field!

Comment: Assuming you're talking about signed differences rather than the absolute difference, yes.