# When`starmap` could be preferred over `List Comprehension`

Tags: python, list-comprehension, python-itertools

While answering the question [Clunky calculation of differences between an incrementing set of numbers, is there a more beautiful way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448122/clunky-calculation-of-differences-between-an-incrementing-set-of-numbers-is-the), I came up with two solutions, one with `List Comprehension` and other using [itertools.starmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap).

To me, `list comprehension` Syntax looks more lucid, readable, less verbose and more Pythonic. But still as [starmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) is well available in itertools, I was wondering, there has to be a reason for it.

My Question is when`starmap` could be preferred over `List Comprehension`?

**Note** If its a matter of Style then it definitely contradicts `There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.`

**Head to Head Comparison**

*Readability counts.* --- `LC`

Its again a matter of perception but to me `LC` is more readable than `starmap`.
To use `starmap`, either you need to import `operator`, or define `lambda` or some explicit `multi-variable` function and nevertheless extra import from `itertools`.

*Performance*         --- `LC`

```
>>> def using_star_map(nums):
    delta=starmap(sub,izip(nums[1:],nums))
    return sum(delta)/float(len(nums)-1)
>>> def using_LC(nums):
    delta=(x-y for x,y in izip(nums[1:],nums))
    return sum(delta)/float(len(nums)-1)
>>> nums=[random.randint(1,10) for _ in range(100000)]
>>> t1=Timer(stmt='using_star_map(nums)',setup='from __main__ import nums,using_star_map;from itertools import starmap,izip')
>>> t2=Timer(stmt='using_LC(nums)',setup='from __main__ import nums,using_LC;from itertools import izip')
>>> print "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t1.timeit(number=1000)/100000)
235.03 usec/pass
>>> print "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t2.timeit(number=1000)/100000)
181.87 usec/pass
```

Comment: I don't think it's fair to compare them the way you did. Both functions should save the differences to `deltas` because at the moment the `using_star_map` is less readable since it is all in one line. Change it to: `deltas = starmap(sub,zip(nums[1:],nums))` `sum(deltas)/float(len(nums)-1)`

Comment: @jamylak: Thank you for pointing it out. But unfortunately it doesn't change the performance difference.

Comment: It wasn't meant to but we are also talking about readability.

Comment: You might like to post a code example that does not require extensive fixing before it can be used.

Answer (score 13):

The difference I normally see is `map()`/`starmap()` are most appropriate where you are literally just calling a function on every item in a list. In this case, they are a little clearer:

```
(f(x) for x in y)
map(f, y) # itertools.imap(f, y) in 2.x

(f(*x) for x in y)
starmap(f, y)
```

As soon as you start needing to throw in `lambda` or `filter` as well, you should switch up to the list comp/generator expression, but in cases where it's a single function, the syntax feels very verbose for a generator expression of list comprehension.

They *are* interchangeable, and where in doubt, stick to the generator expression as it's more readable in general, but in a simple case (`map(int, strings)`, `starmap(Vector, points)`) using `map()`/`starmap()`  can sometimes make things easier to read.

## Example:

An example where I think `starmap()` is more readable:

```
from collections import namedtuple
from itertools import starmap

points = [(10, 20), (20, 10), (0, 0), (20, 20)]

Vector = namedtuple("Vector", ["x", "y"])

for vector in (Vector(*point) for point in points):
    ...

for vector in starmap(Vector, points):
    ...
```

And for `map()`:

```
values = ["10", "20", "0"]

for number in (int(x) for x in values):
    ...

for number in map(int, values):
    ...
```

## Performance:

```
python -m timeit -s "from itertools import starmap" -s "from operator import sub" -s "numbers = zip(range(100000), range(100000))" "sum(starmap(sub, numbers))"                         
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.258 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s "numbers = zip(range(100000), range(100000))" "sum(x-y for x, y in numbers)"                          
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.446 usec per loop
```

For constructing a `namedtuple`:

```
python -m timeit -s "from itertools import starmap" -s "from collections import namedtuple" -s "numbers = zip(range(100000), reversed(range(100000)))" -s "Vector = namedtuple('Vector', ['x', 'y'])" "list(starmap(Vector, numbers))"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.98 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s "from collections import namedtuple" -s "numbers = zip(range(100000), reversed(range(100000)))" -s "Vector = namedtuple('Vector', ['x', 'y'])" "[Vector(*pos) for pos in numbers]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.375 usec per loop
```

In my tests, where we are talking about using simple functions (no `lambda`), `starmap()` is faster than the equivalent generator expression. Naturally, performance should take a back-seat to readability unless it's a proven bottleneck.

Example of how `lambda` kills any performance gain, same example as in the first set, but with `lambda` instead of `operator.sub()`:

```
python -m timeit -s "from itertools import starmap" -s "numbers = zip(range(100000), range(100000))" "sum(starmap(lambda x, y: x-y, numbers))" 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.546 usec per loop
```

Comment: `map(f, y)` is equivalent for `[f(x) for x in y]` and not for `(f(x) for x in y)`, because it is not a generator. It executes at once.

Comment: @akaRem Lattyware always uses python 3.

Comment: @akaRem Sorry, I'm talking Python 3.x - indeed, in 2.x, that is true. Updated to clarify.

Comment: @Lattyware: I agree with map, but when you are dealing with `starmap`, generally speaking that involves extra `import`, may be `multivariable function definition` if  not `lambda` and nevertheless end up importing `operators`, and my current question is the usability of `starmap`.

Comment: @Abhijit I added an example of a use case for `starmap()`. As I say, wherever you need `lambda` you have pushed `map()`/`starmap()` beyond what they are designed to use, and you should switch to a generator expression.

Comment: I like the use case of `starmap`, it is a very good example IMO.

Comment: @Lattyware: Its really a good case for using `starmap`. I will `timeit` now and see how both fairs.

Answer (score 3):

It's largely a style thing. Choose whichever you find more readable.

In relation to "There's only one way to do it", Sven Marnach kindly provides this [Guido quote](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2011-October/012511.html):

> “You may think this violates TOOWTDI, but as I've said before, that
>   was a white lie (as well a cheeky response to Perl's slogan around
>   2000). Being able to express intent (to human readers) often requires
>   choosing between multiple forms that do essentially the same thing,
>   but look different to the reader.”

In a performance hotspot, you might want to choose the solution which runs fastest (which I guess in this case would be the `starmap` based one).

On performance - starmap is slower because of its destructuring; however starmap is not necessary here:

```
from timeit import Timer
import random
from itertools import starmap, izip,imap
from operator import sub

def using_imap(nums):
    delta=imap(sub,nums[1:],nums[:-1])
    return sum(delta)/float(len(nums)-1)

def using_LC(nums):
    delta=(x-y for x,y in izip(nums[1:],nums))
    return sum(delta)/float(len(nums)-1)

nums=[random.randint(1,10) for _ in range(100000)]
t1=Timer(stmt='using_imap(nums)',setup='from __main__ import nums,using_imap')
t2=Timer(stmt='using_LC(nums)',setup='from __main__ import nums,using_LC')
```

On my computer:

```
>>> print "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t1.timeit(number=1000)/100000)
172.86 usec/pass
>>> print "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t2.timeit(number=1000)/100000)
178.62 usec/pass
```

`imap` comes out a tiny bit faster, probably because it avoids zipping/destructuring.

Comment: But Zen of Python says `There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.`

Comment: @Abhijit Yes, but you shouldn't believe everything you read. Python frequently has several equally good ways of accomplishing a given task.

Comment: But isn't this the Python's Core Philosophy which makes it different from `Ruby`, `Perl` ....

Comment: @Abhijit It's a nice easter egg, and a lot of it is good advice ("simple is better than complex"), but just because it's included in the interpreter it doesn't make it into come kind of computer scientific law.

Comment: Quoting [Guido van Rossum](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2011-October/012511.html): “You may think this violates TOOWTDI, but as I've said before, that was
a white lie (as well a cheeky response to Perl's slogan around 2000).
Being able to express intent (to human readers) often requires
choosing between multiple forms that do essentially the same thing,
but look different to the reader.”

Comment: @SvenMarnach Or even more simply - *'practicality beats purity'*. There will always be more than one way to do something - that's a reality of the power of the language. The real meaning of the Zen of Python's line is more about reducing language clutter and avoiding pointless synonyms.

Comment: @Lattyware: Of course, this catch-all rule can be applied to explain just any inconsistency! :)

Comment: Just a note on performance: if you're actually calling a pre-existing function, `starmap` seems a little bit faster in my `timeit` tests, but if you have to define a `lambda` to do it, the generator expression will almost definitely win by avoiding function calls.

Comment: @Dougal Yes. In general map/starmap seem to outperform list comprehensions when passed a builtin (that is, written in C) function.

Comment: `which I guess in this case would be the starmap based one`, if you see my update, With a little modification instead of using LC but generator expression, it outperformed starmap. And isn't it possible to rewrite an LC as a generator expression?

Comment: @Abhijit That's not a fair comparison. You're still using zip in the starmap version.

Comment: @Marcin: Changing to izip didn't change the performance difference considerably. Btw thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Marcin: Looks if the items are already zipped, `starmap` could be a good alternative but a close contender with generator expression. If items needs to be zipped using `imap` vs `generator expression` would be purely based on readability.

Answer (score 2):

**About Starmap..** 
Lets say you have `L = [(0,1,2),(3,4,5),(6,7,8),..]`.

Generator comprehansion would look like

```
(f(a,b,c) for a,b,c in L)
```

or

```
(f(*item) for item in L)
```

And starmap would look like

```
starmap(f, L)
```

The third variant is lighter and shorter. But first one is very obvious and it doesnt force me to thing what does it do.

Ok. Now I want to write more complicated in-line code..

```
some_result = starmap(f_res, [starmap(f1,L1), starmap(f2,L2), starmap(f3,L3)])
```

This line is not obvious, but still easy to understand..
In generator comprehansion it would look like:

```
some_result = (f_res(a,b,c) for a,b,c in [(f1(a,b,c) for a,b,c in L1), (f2(a,b,c) for a,b,c in L2), (f3(a,b,c) for a,b,c in L3)])
```

As you see, it is long, heavy to understand and could not be placed in one line, because it is larger than 79 characters (PEP 8). Even shorter variant is bad:

```
some_result = (f_res(*item) for item [(f1(*item) for item in L1), (f(*item2) for item in L2), (f3(*item) for item in L3)])
```

Too many characters.. Too many brackets.. Too much noise.

**So. Starmap in some cases is a very useful tool. With it you can write less code that is simpler to understand.**

**EDIT** added some dummy tests

```
from timeit import timeit
print timeit("from itertools import starmap\nL = [(0,1,2),(3,4,5),(6,7,8)]\nt=list((max(a,b,c)for a,b,c in L))")
print timeit("from itertools import starmap\nL = [(0,1,2),(3,4,5),(6,7,8)]\nt=list((max(*item)for item in L))")
print timeit("from itertools import starmap\nL = [(0,1,2),(3,4,5),(6,7,8)]\nt=list(starmap(max,L))")
```

outputs (python 2.7.2)

```
5.23479851154
5.35265309689
4.48601346328
```

So, starmap is even ~15% faster here.

Comment: I would argue that in your more complex case, both `starmap()` and generator expressions are not a good solution. It's more readable to expand out your code (into a full generator, for example) at that point.