# How do I pass tuples elements to a function as arguments?

Tags: python, list, arguments, tuples

I have a list consisting of tuples, I want to pass each tuple's elements to a function as arguments:

```
mylist = [(a, b), (c, d), (e, f)]

myfunc(a, b)
myfunc(c, d)
myfunc(e, f)
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is actually very simple to do in Python, simply loop over the list and use the splat operator (`*`) to unpack the tuple as arguments for the function:

```
mylist = [(a, b), (c, d), (e, f)]
for args in mylist:
    myfunc(*args)
```

E.g:

```
>>> numbers = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
>>> for args in numbers:
...     print(*args)
... 
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

Comment: (1) .. you are too fast! :) (2) is this something specific to v3.x? I didn't think so, but I get a invalid syntax error when I tried something similar to your 2nd example my data was ('a','b') .. etc. I'm using v2.x

Comment: See also `itertools.starmap`.

Comment: The `func(*args)` syntax is not specific to 3.x, but `print` being a function is so the example will give a syntax error on `print(*args)` on 2.x.

Comment: @F.J .. thanks! How odd since I regularly use the function syntax to print strings, numbers etc with v 2.x .. so it must be specific to this argument .. is there a way for me to do this with v2.x? `print *args` is no good. Maybe time for me to also install 3.x

Comment: You may think you are using `print` as a function on 2.x because you use parentheses, but the parentheses aren't actually doing anything if there is only one value.  For example `print(1)` is the same thing as `print 1`.  You can do the same thing with other statements as well, for example `return(1)` is equivalent to `return 1`.

Comment: On Python 2.x you could create a simple function that just prints out each argument, for example you could use `def _print(*args): print ' '.join(map(str, args))`

Comment: Another option in Python 2.x is to import the print function from the future - `from __future__ import print_function`.

Comment: @Lattyware: It's called the "splat" operator? I had no idea.

Comment: @DSM I would avoid that. Generally a list comprehension/generator expression is a better option, [give or take a few rare cases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448486/whenstarmap-could-be-preferred-over-list-comprehension/10448628#10448628). Here you are not aiming to build up a list, or make a generator, so I would say a normal loop is best.

Comment: @JoelCornett It gets called that a lot. Some people also call it the *star* operator for obvious reasons. I don't think it's an official name, but it's reasonably well known.

Comment: @JoelCornett In the documentation it is just called [Unpacking Argument Lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), and they just call it the `*`-operator there.

Comment: How about adding an example with tuple unpacking: `for x, y in mylist: ...`?

Answer (score 1):

To make @DSM's comment explicit:

```
>>> from itertools import starmap
>>> list(starmap(print, ((1,2), (3,4), (5,6)))) 
# 'list' is used here to force the generator to run out.
# You could instead just iterate like `for _ in starmap(...): pass`, etc.
1 2
3 4
5 6
[None, None, None] # the actual created list;
# `print` returns `None` after printing.
```

Comment: I would argue this is a bad idea - you are constructing a list where you don't actually want one. It's ugly and not clear.

Comment: The `starmap` iterator can be used however it needs to be used. In situations where we want to "pass each tuple's elements to a function as arguments", it's common to want to do something with the results of the function calls, too. If not, `for _ in starmap(...): pass` is appropriate.

Comment: It does the job, but why do it instead of a normal for loop? It's much less clear for anyone reading that code.