# Pass multiple arguments in form of tuple

Tags: python, class, object, arguments, tuples

I'm passing a lot data around; specifically, I'm trying to pass the output of a function into a class and the output contains a tuple with three variables. I can't directly pass the output from my function (the tuple) into the class as in the input parameters.

How can format the tuple so it is accepted by the class without `input_tuple[0], input_tuple[1], input_tuple[2]`?

Here is a simple example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class InputStuff(object):

    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c


input_tuple = (1, 2, 3)
instance_1 = InputStuff(input_tuple)

# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "Untitled 3.py", line 7, in <module>
#     instance_1 = InputStuff(input_tuple)
# TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)

InputStuff(1, 2, 3)
# This works
```

Comment: `instance_1 = InputStuff(*input_tuple)` - see http://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/3001761

Comment: that worked, can you put that as an answer so i can mark it correct?

Comment: I've told you what the duplicate is - I'd close it, but I've run out of votes! (Thanks @BhargavRao)

Comment: @Jonrsharpe I see that it may be a duplicate but if someone doesn't know about the * operator or that unpacking an argument list with * is a possibility then they won't search that to find the answer. I think the wording of the title is very straight forward in a search.

Comment: You mean like http://stackoverflow.com/q/1993727/3001761, http://stackoverflow.com/q/10625220/3001761, ...? How many different versions do you think we need?

Comment: @Jonrsharpe, those definitely explain it.  I didn't see them when I was searching.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `*` operator to [unpack the argument list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
input_tuple = (1,2,3)
instance_1 = InputStuff(*input_tuple)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for:
[`Unpacking Argument Lists`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists)

```
>>> range(3, 6)             # normal call with separate arguments
[3, 4, 5]
>>> args = [3, 6]
>>> range(*args)            # call with arguments unpacked from a list
[3, 4, 5]
```