# How to pass a tuple as arguments to a Lua function?

Tags: function, lua, tuples

Is there a way to pass a tuple as the parameters of a Lua function?

For example, I have a function that returns multiple values

```
function f(a,b)  return b,a end
```

and I want this function `f` to be repeatedly applied, so I can write:

```
f (f ... f(1,2))
```

But what if I need to store this initial tuple `(1,2)` as a variable `init`?

```
f (f ... f(init))
```

Is there support for this?

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10625231/683218), it seems python has it with the splat operator `*`.

Comment: "*so I can write*" That's not valid Lua. `f ... f` isn't legal Lua syntax. So I don't understand what you want here.

Comment: [This page](http://lua-users.org/wiki/FunctionalTuples) may help you.

Comment: @NicolBolas You can write e.g. `f( f (1,2)),  f (f ( f(1,2) ) ) ` etc., for any number of applications of `f`. That's what I meant with the `...` , and `repeatedly apply`.

Comment: I think you want this code I've written in the past: http://hawwashsoft.proboards.com/thread/187/varargmodule

Answer (score 12):

Lua does not have "tuples".

When a function returns multiple values, it returns *multiple values*. They aren't put together into some data structure; they're separate values. If you want to store multiple return values in a single data structure, you have to actually do that.

Lua 5.2 has the `table.pack` function, which you can use to store multiple return values in a table. But it does so in such a way that you can decompose them later:

```
local values = table.pack(f(1, 2))

f(table.unpack(values, values.n))
```

`unpack` exists in Lua 5.1, but `pack` does not. You can emulate it easily enough:

```
function pack(...)
    return {n = select("#", ...), ...}
end
```

Comment: `{...}` is also valid, it will add each of the values to an indexed table.

Comment: @RichardSmith: But you wouldn't be able to get the length properly. If one of the parameters is `nil`, that will count as the end of the list even though `...` can carry `nil` values.