# What is the most pythonic way to avoid specifying the same value in a string

Tags: python, string, formatting

```
message = "hello %s , how are you %s, welcome %s"%("john","john","john")
```

What is the most pythonic way to avoid specifying "john" 3 times and instead to specify one phrase.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
"hello %(name)s , how are you %(name)s, welcome %(name)s" % {"name": "john"}
'hello john, how are you john, welcome john'
```

This is another way to do this without using format.

Answer (score 24):

I wouldn't use `%` formatting, `.format` has many advantages. Also `%` formatting was originally planned to be removed with `.format` replacing it, although apparently this hasn't actually happened.

> A new system for built-in string formatting operations replaces the `%` string formatting operator. (However, the `%` operator is still supported; it will be deprecated in Python 3.1 and removed from the language at some later time.) Read [PEP 3101](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101) for the full scoop.

```
>>> "hello {name}, how are you {name}, welcome {name}".format(name='john')
'hello john, how are you john, welcome john'
```

I prefer the first way since it is explicit, but here is a reason why `.format` is superior over `%` formatting

```
>>> "hello {0}, how are you {0}, welcome {0}".format('john')
'hello john, how are you john, welcome john'
```

Answer (score 3):

This works also:

```
"hello %s , how are you %s, welcome %s"%tuple(["john"]*3)
```

or even shorter, without the explicit type cast:

```
"hello %s , how are you %s, welcome %s"%(("john",)*3)
```

Comment: I disagree. This is pythonic short and easy.

Comment: *"There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."*

Comment: The reality shows there is almost always more than one way to do it also in Python.

Comment: Of couse, in any language there has to be more than one way of doing something, however that isn't what the quote is saying. *"There should be one-- and preferably only one --**obvious way** to do it."*

Comment: @jamylak: Please see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448486/whenstarmap-could-be-preferred-over-list-comprehension#comment13490090_10448537).  I would encourage you to use downvotes for outright wrong answers, or answers that do not answer the question, not for answers you stylistically disagree with.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Alright that's true, point taken, I will remove downvote.

Answer (score 1):

99% likely you should use .format()

It's unlikely but if you had a series of greetings you could try this:

```
>>> greetings = ["hello", "how are you", "welcome"]
>>> ", ".join(" ".join((greet, "John")) for greet in greetings)
'hello John, how are you John, welcome John'
```